# Access Django API via Heroku returns "detail": "Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request."

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I deployed my Django project on Heroku with gunicorn. It's basically only the api (no templates).
When I deploy heroku and access `<heroku url>/api/login` for example in the browser
and post login data already in json format, it always returns
`"detail": "Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request."`

But when I do the same on localhost, the user gets authenticated and I receive a response with user data...

post data example for login:
 `{ "email": "ana@test.com", "password": "ana1234567890" }`

The `parser_classes = [JSONParser]` is added on every view where I don't have images or files (there I am using FileUploadParser).

**I deployed on Heroku with gunicorn, because on localhost I permanently received "Unauthorized" from backend ( Permission Class is "isAuthenticated" for most of my views).** After some research I figured out that probably the authorization header is not sent (here the APACHE WSGIPassAuthorization On would be a solution) **but I don't have an apache server running and I don't want no webserver running on my machine.**

I thought if I would deploy it on heroku with gunicorn, I could continue with the development without the "Unautorized" header but instead I run in other errors, like `"detail": "Unsupported media type \"application/x-www-form-urlencoded\" in request."` .. or the database connection is refused.

In my frontend I am sending the following header

```
    // Headers
    const token_config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}',
        //withCredentials : true,
      },
    };
```

And the frontend is of course also receiving the "Wrong mediatype Error" .

I would be so greatfull if anybody could provide an detailed "howTo" for Django DRF + postgres on Heroku... I've wen't through lots of howtos, but none of them provides a fitting solution for this..

My main questions now are...

- What does settings.py need so that the backend works on heroku just as fine as on localhost?
- Do I really need to start the heroku postgres database manually with
  heroku pg:psql postgresql-shaped-60432 --app  every time after deployment? - Because If I don't, the herocu log shows:

  ```
   2020-09-09T11:11:15.028985+00:00 app[web.1]: connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
   2020-09-09T11:11:15.028985+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
   2020-09-09T11:11:15.028986+00:00 app[web.1]: conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
   2020-09-09T11:11:15.028986+00:00 app[web.1]: django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
   2020-09-09T11:11:15.028987+00:00 app[web.1]: Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
   2020-09-09T11:11:15.028987+00:00 app[web.1]: TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
  ```

With this error + accessing the /api/login for example, I get an HTTP status of 503 or 500...

My requirements.txt:

```
Django==3.1.1
django-allauth==0.42.0
django-cors-headers==3.5.0
django-environ==0.4.5
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
django-sslserver==0.20
djangorestframework==3.11.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.1.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
image==1.5.27
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
oauthlib==3.1.0
Pillow==7.2.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
PyJWT==1.7.1
```

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it!

I basically had to add all the settings.py stuff:

```
    import django_heroku
    import dj_database_url

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='URI from Heroku-color- postgres database')}

    # ALL THE STATIC PATHS
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    
    #location where django collect all static files
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')# location where you will store your static files
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'walkAdog/static')]
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'


    # for deployement on heroku
    django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

AT THIS POINT the origin error `“detail”: “Unsupported media type \”application/x-www-form-urlencoded\“ in request.”` did not appear anymore

.. But the next error occured: No module named 'django_heroku'...
So I figured out, that django-heroku was not installed correctly, since the `pipenv install psycopg` crashed - worked for me as I did `installed pipenv install psycopg2==2.7.7` and then `django whitenoise dj-database-url psycopg2`

instead, the database was "empty" - quite predictable..

So I did makemigrations on localhost
then commit the project/migrations folder (and the rest)
and ran heroku run python manage.py migrate

**-> everything working fine now!!**

Basically, I just had to follow the steps from https://medium.com/@hdsingh13/deploying-django-app-on-heroku-with-postgres-as-backend-b2f3194e8a43 .. I just kinda didn't understand the neccessarity of all the stuff..